# What is a Wiki Edit?

Tags: support, edits, tag-wiki, community-wiki, terminology

What actually constitutes a "wiki edit" on Stack Exchange? How is that different to a normal question edit?

I have looked at the first 50-60 related questions and they all involve details.

For example in the badge definitions "non wiki answers", or "tag wiki edit".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Tag wikis are the information that is attached to tags, like [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/support/info) for the [support](/questions/tagged/support) tag here. Tag wiki edits refer to editing that information.

Community wiki answers are answers that were made "Community wiki" by their authors or after having had many edits. Exact details [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts).

Comment: thank you. the detailed link helped. I never saw the word "wiki" on this site save for the badge definitions... seems it is a little grey box under the answer text editor. Good to know. how does one go about editing the tag wiki content? or submitting requests for updates?

Comment: There's a big `Edit tag wiki` button on the tag wiki page. Click on that :)

Comment: smarty pants, where is your "tag wiki" page in the first place? the only place I have seen anything about tag wiki's is selecting a tag to see its relative questions and something at the top stating "this tag doesnt have a tag wiki entry; help us create it", which is helpful, but not the same.

Comment: The "help us create it" link allows you to create a tag wiki (which is kind of a form of edit). If you click on the first link in my post, you'll see that button. If you click on the tag that follows it, you'll see a "learn more..." link which you should click.

Comment: i see that; i'm not stupid, but apparently unable to phrase my question well enough. thanks for your help and info.